# Can values be set for CMake SOURCE(S) other than using set?

Tags: c++, cmake

Suppose I have a simple C++ hello-world project with the following CMake script:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

project(hello)

set(SOURCE main.cpp)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE})
```

Now I noticed that `PROJECT_NAME` is built-in and its *value* is set from `project(*value*)` but also `SOURCE` (and `SOURCES`) seems to be provided by CMake too.

Are there other ways where `SOURCE` can be assigned with project source files? Just like the same behavior with `PROJECT_NAME`. Or is `set(SOURCE ...)` the intended method.

I'm new to CMake. The `SOURCE` and `SOURCES` variables were colored out on my text editor. I'm confused.

Comment: Neither `SOURCE` nor `SOURCES` variable is automatically set by CMake. So you may use (or not use) these variables as you want. You may find list of all predefined variables in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-variables.7.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `SOURCE` variable is a common patter in CMake files, but it is not required.

The code above can be written without any variables, it would look something like this:

```
add_executable(hello main.cpp)
```

When there are a lot of source files, passing them all to `add_executable` can be inconvenient. Another alternative is `target_sources`:

```
add_executable(hello)

target_sources(hello PRIVATE main.cpp)
```

Comment: So much extra thanks for recommending target_sources() as an alternative :)